# SyntaxError when processing continuation-local-storage/contex.js

Tags: rollupjs

I'm attempting to use Rollup to generate a tree-shaken, minified script to deploy to AWS Lambda. However rollup seems to be choking on the continuation-local-storage library for some reason.

Error:

```
Error: Unexpected token
    at error (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:5154:30)
    at Module.error (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9592:16)
    at tryParse (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9506:23)
    at Module.setSource (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9890:30)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17742:20)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17796:9) {
  code: 'PARSE_ERROR',
  parserError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (24:0)
      at Object.pp$4.raise (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15064:13)
      at Object.pp.unexpected (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12835:8)
      at Object.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12975:120)
      at Object.pp$1.parseIfStatement (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13136:26)
      at Object.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12980:31)
      at Object.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12892:21)
      at Object.parse (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12692:15)
      at Function.parse (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12715:35)
      at tryParse (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9493:23)
      at Module.setSource (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9890:30)
      at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17742:20)
      at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17796:9) {
    pos: 418,
    loc: Position { line: 24, column: 0 },
    raisedAt: 426
  },
  id: '/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js',
  pos: 418,
  loc: {
    file: '/Users/chris/Code/box-stack/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js',
    line: 17,
    column: 0
  },
  frame: '15: if (!process.addAsyncListener) ' +
    "require('async-listener');\n16: \n17: function " +
    'Namespace(name) {\n    ^\n18:   this.name   = name;\n19:   // ' +
    'changed in 2.7: no default context',
  watchFiles: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

The offending code (continuation-local-storage/context.js line 17, position 0) is:

```
function Namespace(name) {
```

I don't see how there could be a syntax error here:

I'm running rollup through the javascript api since I need to programmatically generate the inputs here's the bit where I'm invoking the build:

```
try {
    const build = await rollup({
      external: ['aws-sdk', ...builtinModules],
      input,
      plugins: [
        commonjs(),
        nodeResolve({ extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.node', '.mjs'] }),
        json(),
        babel({ extensions: ['.ts'], babelHelpers: 'bundled' })
      ]
    });
    await build.write({
      dir: outDir,
      format: 'cjs',
      entryFileNames: '[name].js',
      sourcemap: false
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error in the exact same place, also trying to get something tree-shakable with generated inputs - did you get anywhere with it?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, there is a workaround:

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/202

Add a replace:

```
plugins: [
  replace({"if (!process.addAsyncListener) require('async-listener": "require('async-listener"})
]
```